# Use MSBuild 3.5 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

How can I force Visual Studio 2010 to use MSBuild 3.5 instead of the new 4.0 ?

Comment: I have a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895872/targeting-net3-5-with-asp-net-mvc2-web-application-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can't change the version of MSBuild used within Visual Studio without a dirty hack.

### ToolsVersion

The version of MSBuild tasks, targets, and tools used by MSBuild is determined by the **ToolsVersion** attribute in the project file.

- Visual Studio 2008 uses ToolsVersion="3.5"
- Visual Studio 2010 uses ToolsVersion="4.0"

Problem : If you change the ToolsVersion manually to 3.5 on the project file, Visual Studio 2010 will automatically upgrade the project file's ToolsVersion to 4.0

### The hack

The solution is to set your project ToolsVersion to 3.6 (or whatever or 4.0 if you **really** want to override MSBuild 4.0) and then in the registry to create the following key :

- Registry Hive: `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\3.6`
- String Key Name: `MSBuildToolsPath`
- String Key Value: `.NET Framework 3.5 Install Path` (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5)

On machine where ToolsVersion is unknown, the default ToolsVersion will be used.

*More information on [custom toolset definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397428.aspx).*

Comment: On machines MSBuild 3.5 is used to build VS2010 csproj, MSBuild 3.5 simply treats ToolsVersion="4.0" as ToolsVersion="3.5". So VS2010 project files can still be built by MSBuild 3.5 in some scenarios (especially when you ask VS2010 to build against .NET 3.5 instead of 4).

Comment: The hack sounds interesting... but would have to do it on any machines that will build the project right? Not so good for a team project probably - would also need to add hack to the TFS build server I guess. Might be useful during a migration from framework to framework.. might try it out

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want that? Is there anything 3.5 capable but 4.0 not?

If your real concern is that when the code is checked out to a machine that does not have .NET 4 installed, you can use MSBuild 3.5 to build the projects (csproj). You need to create a solution file for MSBuild 3.5 as it does not accept the sln file of VS2010.

When MSBuild comes across ToolsVersion="4.0" it will treat it as ToolsVersion="3.5" and then everything continues to work.

My open source project #SNMP utilizes such tricks so the source code can be built on .NET 4, .NET 3.5 and Mono.

Comment: To use VS 2010 with a project that won't work with MSBuild 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can target different versions of runtime from the project properties dialog:

[alt text http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/3051/vstargetframework.png](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/3051/vstargetframework.png)

Not sure if modifying the build rules to use MsBuild 3.5 for C#/VB.NET targets is a good idea.

(The below change is unnecessary. Using .NET 4 targets file has no problem at all.)
**Edit** Try to open the c# project with a text editor and modify this line:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

to this:

```
<Import Project="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

Comment: It doesn't help, as MSBuild 4.0 uses Framework 4.0. We need to target MSBuild 3.5

Comment: See edit, that might help. Not sure what's going to happen to the system references, might need to point those to v3.5 of the assembies if they got converted during Vs2008->VS2010 conversion.

Comment: That won't change the actual executable used either.

Comment: @HeavyWave, what you complain "It doesn't help, as MSBuild 4.0 uses Framework 4.0. We need to target MSBuild 3." is a misunderstanding. Though MSBuild 4 relies on .NET 4, but if you ask it to build your project against earlier .NET versions, you will see the output only depends on old versions, not .NET 4. You don't even need to edit the <Import> tag.

Comment: The output yes, but MSBuild itself references .Net 4.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 also references .NET 4 assemblies, but it has nothing to do with build results right? Then why you cannot use MSBuild 4?

Comment: I found an issue with a web application. Between 3.5 and 4.0, classes moved from System.Web.Security to System.Web.ApplicationServices. Changing the Target Framework doesn't help, still need to reference 4.0 library. Necessary to change the toolset in this case I believe.