# Targeting .NET3.5 with ASP.NET MVC2 Web Application in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, backwards-compatibility

Our current environment is .NET 3.5 SP1 but we're in the process of migrating to .NET4 and Visual Studio 2010.

I would like to stick to using .NET 3.5 for the deployment/production environment however use Visual Studio and TFS 2010 for development, until the production environment is cleared for upgrade to .NET4. Is this possible (I assume yes :B), and how?

What I have tried is changing the TargetFrameworkVersion in the project settings to "v3.5". However, I get a build failure due to the classes in System.Web.Security that moved to System.Web.ApplicationServices in .NET 4 (e.g. MembershipUser) not being found... so it appears that it is using .NET4 libraries and not .NET3.5? Do I add the System.Web.ApplicationServices library to my project, and if so, does this mean it will still run on .NET 3.5?

Also, I noticed that the ToolsVersion of the project is 4.0, would changing it from 4.0 to 3.5 be the correct thing to do? When I do this, re-opening the project causes Visual Studio to run the conversion process, changing the ToolsVersion back to 4.0 ...

Cheers,

James

Comment: Similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770361/use-msbuild-3-5-with-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Starting to think that changing the toolset is the way to go, and ignore VS2010's conversion... or continue to use VS2008 until I can switch to .NET4 :(

Answer (score 0):

You must have Visual Studio 2008 installed to be able to target .NET 3.5 in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Surely I should only need the 3.5 framework, which is under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5 for the tooling and C:\Windows\assembly for the GAC? I ended up not needing to stick to v3.5 though, so I guess this will remain open.