# What are the specific version numbers of the C# 4, 5 and 6 compilers and how to know which one Visual Studio is using to compile my project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I know that I've got the C# 6 compiler and I use C# 6 features often and when I write applications to practice, I usually target .NET v4.6.

On this machine, I have Visual Studio 2010, 2013, 2015 and 2017 installed.

When I type `csc.exe` from the .NET Framework v4 directory, it shows me the compiler version as **4.6.1098.0 for C# 5**, which is very confusing.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>csc Microsoft (R)
>   Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1098.0 for C# 5 Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework,
>   but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the
>   latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C#
>   programming language, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

And when I type the same command on another laptop of mine where I have only Visual Studio 2013 installed, I get the following output from the `csc.exe` command.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>csc Microsoft (R)
>   Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1055.0 for C# 5 Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework,
>   but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the
>   latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C#
>   programming language, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

Observe that it reads **4.6.1055.0 for C# 5**.

1. So, my first question is: what are the different version numbers of the C# compilers for C# 4, 5 and 6?
2. Second, how do I know which version of the `csc.exe` file, and thus which version of the C# compiler, my Visual Studio installation is using to compile my files? To try this on my own, I created a console application on each of my two machines and chased down the project files. They both had an MS Build `Import` directive for the `Microsoft.Csharp.targets` file from the MS Build `bin` folder. But I gave up reading from inside that file because I still don't fully understand all of the MS Build tags.

Comment: Not real sure what the question is here. C# 5 obviously uses version 4.6 of the compiler. Where does the confusion come in? The other number ("1098") is just a minor revision/build number; presumably, there were multiple revisions made to the C# compiler. The first system you tried has a slightly newer version, probably a bug fix or two. They're both C# 5. Also, the compilers are backwards-compatible, meaning that the C# 5 compiler can target an older version of C#. You configure this with project options and/or compiler switches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between C# compiler version and language version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814922/difference-between-c-sharp-compiler-version-and-language-version)

Comment: @CodyGray You could be right. The reason I ask is: on the VS 2013 machine, C# 5 features such as `CallerMemberAttribute` don't work. I wanted to know which version of the C# compiler VS 2013 was using to compile my code.

Comment: However, it does recognize the keywords `async` and `await`, which I believe were introduced in C# 5.

Answer (score 1):

> what are the different version numbers of the C# compilers for C# 4, 5 and 6?

As the latest C# versions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2013 are use the C# 4 & 5 compiler, and just as Cody Gray said, *the compilers are backwards-compatible, meaning that the C# 5 compiler can target an older version of C#.*  So they are both C# 5. Besides, [starting with Visual Studio 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio/), MSBuild and the C# compilers are now available as a standalone package,Microsoft® Build Tools. This package is installed with Visual Studio 2013. Then you can get the version number of the C# 6 from the path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0

> how do I know which version of the csc.exe file, and thus which version of the C# compiler, my Visual Studio installation is using to compile my files?

The csc.exe file in MSBuild folder is internal used by MSBuild. You can get the C# compiler version from the path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\csc.exe`

[image]

Comment: Hasn't the C# compiler *always* been available as a standalone package? Originally, it shipped with the .NET Framework. I'm not sure if that's still true, since I've been mostly avoiding .NET for the past couple of releases.

Comment: Yes, the C# compiler was available as a standalone package and shipped with the .net Framwork before Visual Studio 2013, starting from VS2013, C# compiler shipped with Visual Studio.