# Any way how to force Equals to return false instead of Null reference exception?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, equals-operator

I ran into a null reference exception on line:

```
dr["IsSandpit"] = p.MineralName.Equals("Sand");
```

Of course the fix is:

```
dr["IsSandpit"] = p.MineralName!=null && p.MineralName.Equals("Sand");
```

But I am wondering if a nullable type can be configured that the Equals method instead of throwing a null reference exception would just return `false` for a strongly typed variable? Or some method `NotNullAndEquals`?

Null in the database means something like "not filled" or empty and "empty" surely is not equal to "Sand". (Perhaps this is a duplicate but I have not found the right question)

Comment: `"Sand".Equals(p.MineralName)`?

Comment: `p.MineralName == "Sand"`

Comment: Your interpretation of the issue is slightly off, which is changing your expectations. The exception is not thrown _inside_ the `Equals()` function, it's merely the consequence of trying to access _anything_ from a `null` value. Whether you were trying to access a property, method, or field is irrelevant, the NRE will be thrown regardless. If you want to implement a workaround here, it should be implemented for the **value**  of `p.MineralName`, not  for the **algorithm** of `.Equals()`. You're "blaming" the wrong party for the exception.

Comment: @mjwills But I sometimes put arguments to Equals like culture.

Comment: In that case, use @Rawling's solution. For a straight up equals, use `==`.

Comment: string.Equals(p.MineralName, "Sand")

Comment: dr["IsSandpit"] = (p.MineralName != null ? p.MineralName.Equals("Sand") : false)

Comment: @Flater but MineralName is of type `string`...? And Equals is a static method.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal: `MineralName` is of **type** string, but it has the **value** of `null`. Also, the `Equals()` you used is **not static**. `String.Equals(foo,bar)` is static. `foo.Equals(bar)` is not. Statics are of the form `ClassName.MethodName()`, not `variableName.MethodName()`.

Comment: Ok, I got it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the Null Conditional Operator to check values on objects which might be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796633/using-the-null-conditional-operator-to-check-values-on-objects-which-might-be-nu)

Comment: @Flater Where did you learn that? `Implementations of Equals must not throw exceptions; they should always return a value. For example, if obj is null, the Equals method should return false instead of throwing an ArgumentNullException.` quoted from "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_Object_Equals_System_Object_"
Wasted some time to discover where the bug was coming from

Comment: To serve the community instead of a single particular case, consider the case of comparing two generic types: `==` can't be used as C# doesn't support the operator for generic types; `Equals` throws exception instead of returning bool (contrary to .NET documentation) so we're forced to _always_ precheck for null.

Comment: @mireazma: The documentation cannot possibly refer to `myValue` in `myValue.Equals(myOtherValue)` notation, since a `null` in `myValue` will **always** lead to a null reference exception regardless of the content of the `Equals()` method. As mentioned in your documentation, null handling is expected of the **parameter** of the function, i.e. `obj` in your documentation and `myOtherValue` in my above example.

Comment: @mireazma Additionally, [the documentation you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_Object_Equals_System_Object_) mentions the following: "The static `Equals(Object, Object)` method indicates whether two objects, `objA` and `objB`, are equal. It also enables you to test objects whose value is null for equality." Notice that the **static** `Equals(objA, objB)` is a **different method** than the `objA.Equals(objB)` method we are discussing here.

Comment: @Flater I apologize - you are right, I misread the documentation. And I saw the static method but I wasn't referring to it. I've just read that Eric Lippert mentioned `null` having a type, albeit inaccessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call the static `Equals` method on both operands:

```
var isEqual =  string.Equals("Sand", p.MineralName); // return false for null.
```

This will remove the need to access a potentially null reference. 
Alternately, you can use the null propagation operator to avoid the operation if the value is null:

```
var isEqual = p.MineralName?.Equals("Sand"); // return null for null.
```

These are much better approaches, IMO, than using extension methods to hack together a method that can theoretically be called on a null reference, since that approach leads to confusion on whether you can safely call a method without checking for null. Imagine this code:

```
 if (!p.MineralName.Equals("Sand"))
 {  
       return p.MineralName.ToUpper(); // throws NullReferencException!
 }
```

Comment: Does the null propagation approach not mean that the resulting value is `null`, rather than `false`? This would implicitly make `var isEqual` of type `int?` rather than `int`.

Comment: " return false for null." - not true, it returns null for null

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
p.MineralName?.Equals("Sand")
```

will evaluate to `null` if `p.MineralName` is null. You can then coalesce it to false, like so:

```
p.MineralName?.Equals("Sand") ?? false
```

Answer (score -1):

As an option you can utilize a self-created **NotNullAndEquals** extension method:

```
    public static class Utilities {
        public static bool NotNullAndEquals(this string value, string expected) {
            return value != null && value.Equals(expected);
        }
    }
```